Saber cuando termina un programa en java desde la consola de netBeans
Mi duda es que si se puede saber de alguna forma cuando terminamos un programa desde la consola de java, desde el boton rojo de detener ejecución, para poder hacer algun proceso cuando ocurra la detención del programa.

Puedes lograr lo que quieres definiendo un ShutdownHook y registrándolo en el objeto Runtime.
Un ejemplo sencillo sería el siguiente
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShutdownSample {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread haltedHook = new Thread(ShutdownSample::ejecutaOnHalt);
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(haltedHook);
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce un entero, por favor");
        System.out.println("El entero introducido es: " + keyboard.nextInt());
    }
        
    private static void ejecutaOnHalt() {
        System.out.println("Esto se acaba, pero la salsa sigue!");
    }
}

Las dos primeras líneas son las que definen y establecen lo que se va a ejecutar SIEMPRE cuando se acabe el programa. Ya sea porque se pulsa el botón rojo de la consola o porque se ha introducido el entero.
Dentro del método ejecutaOnHalt puede poner aquello que quieres que se ejecute antes de que el programa se cierre.
